# How many times will the loop execute?

Tags: for-loop

How many times will the following loop be executed?

```
  for (int i=2; i <=14; i+=3) {
           //body of loop
     }
```

Comment: Please say a bit about why you are asking. What's the problem here? And let us know what you think. What aspect is the unknown for you?

Comment: Programming is about learning how things work. Cant you debug this your self? I can give you the answer easily but im pretty sure that would be counter proactive

Answer (score 1):

`i` will take on the following values, in order (assuming the body of the loop doesn't change it): 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, and finally 17 (at which point, instead of executing the body, the loop terminates), which makes for 5 executions of the body.

```
for (int i=2; i <=14; i+=3) {
       //body of loop
 document.write(i);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

5

```
int count = 0;

for (int i = 2; i <= 14; i += 3) {
    count++;
}

System.out.println("Num times: " + count);
```

Produces

```
Num times: 5
```